# Equivalent to "The Quick Brown Fox...."

Tags: word-choice, hangul

I English, there is a sentence that uses every letter of the (English) alphabet:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs (or slight variants of this)

Here is another, more unusual, example of an English pangram (uses all letters):

> Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.

Are there any such pangrams in Korean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I enjoyed the link that @Display-name left in [his/her answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/3133/91), but I thought I would go ahead and display from that large page of Korean what I believe to be the one passage that [(is a pangram that can be used to type all the characters to test if a keyboard is fully operational)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog).

[image]

This passage of a question and answer (in 2.1, third bullet from end) uses

- all 14 consonants `자음 (ㄱ~ㅎ)`
- all 10 vowels `모음 (ㅏ~ㅣ)`
- all "twin" sounds `된소리(ㄲ, ㄸ, ㅃ, ㅆ, ㅉ)`
- the compound vowels `겹홀소리 (ㅐ,ㅒ, ㅔ,ㅖ,ㅘ, ㅙ, ㅚ, ㅝ, ㅞ, ㅟ, ㅢ)`

> "웬 초콜릿? 제가 원했던 건 뻥튀기 쬐끔과 의류예요." "얘야, 왜 또 불평?"  *

The passage would mean:

> **"Chocolate!? What I wanted was some (조금) rice puffs and clothes."**  **"Child, why are you complaining again?"**

- *Note: there is a footnote on this passage indicating that `조금` is technically spelled incorrectly in order to complete this passage with all required elements.  It is spelled with the colloquial variant `쬐끔`.*

Comment: Note that 쬐끔 is actually a very common colloquial variant of 조금, not just a wild misspelling fabricated to satisfy the conditions. It's just not accepted as an official standard, since there's a rule that two similar words can't be both standard.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you're asking. As you know there are consonants, double consonants, complex consonants, vowels and complex vowels. If you want to write a sentence using all these combinations, it might sound weird (I rarely see multiple complex consonants together).

But [here](https://namu.wiki/w/%ED%8C%AC%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8) are examples which uses different character combinations; ex: consonant only, consonant and vowels.

Refer to [section 2.1](https://namu.wiki/w/%ED%8C%AC%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8#s-2.1)