Is there a famous pangram in Korean?
A pangram is a sentence that uses every single letter in the alphabet at least once. The most famous English pangram is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog," a sentence that's been used since the 1800s to test typewriter ribbons and compare different fonts and typefaces.
Is there such a phrase or a sentence in Korean that uses all Korean alphabets ㄱ,ㄴ,ㄷ,...,ㅍ,ㅎ,ㅏ,ㅑ,ㅓ,,,,,ㅠ,ㅡ,ㅣ?

Duplicate? https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/equivalent-to-the-quick-brown-fox

This question is similar to: Equivalent to "The Quick Brown Fox....". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://namu.wiki/w/%ED%8C%AC%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8#s-2.1
pangram is not popular in korea.
But you could read Namu wiki page about pangram.
한국인들이 많이 이용하는 나무위키 페이지를 참고하세요.

Could you please summarize any relevant sections from that page here? Otherwise this is a link-only answer
